# Useful tools for a11y automation on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, automation, accessibility

I've been looking into accessibility testing for a website on the iphone. Are there any tools for automated testing on-device? If not, what is the closest alternative / most efficient way of going about mobile testing for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Deque has a tool that integrates into Xcode and finds the most common issues http://www.deque.com/products/worldspace/worldspace-xcode-plugin/